# Jinja extends does not render the original base template

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2

This is my base.html template:

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/templates/index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/templates/cheerbot.html">Cheerbot</a></li>
      <li><a href="/templates/encouragement.html">Encouragement</a></li>
    </ul>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class= "chin">
            <bodyblack>C H I N &nbsp; U P, &nbsp; C H E E R &nbsp; U P</bodyblack>
        </div>
        <h1>CHEERBOT</h1>
        <bodyblack>________________________________________________________</bodyblack>
    </div>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
```

This is the child template called cheerbot.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Cheerbot{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>testing</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

This the python code:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True


@app.route('/cheerbot')
def cheerbot():
    return render_template('cheerbot.html')
```

However, the title of the webpage does not show "Cheerbot", and the webpage ends up displaying the raw code instead of extending the base template. What is wrong with it? Thanks in advance.

picture of what the webpage shows me

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkd5Q.png]

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29350463/jinja2-does-not-render-blocks

Answer (score 0):

You have to end body block with name of the block like `{% endblock body %}` :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Cheerbot{% endblock title %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>testing</h1>
{% endblock body %}
```

and same in base.html

```
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="/templates/index.html">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="/templates/cheerbot.html">Cheerbot</a></li>
       <li><a href="/templates/encouragement.html">Encouragement</a></li>
    </ul>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class= "chin">
             <bodyblack>C H I N &nbsp; U P, &nbsp; C H E E R &nbsp; U P</bodyblack>
        </div>
        <h1>CHEERBOT</h1>
          <bodyblack>________________________________________________________</bodyblack>
    </div>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock body %}
```

Run this python program then open browser and type http://localhost:5000/

```
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True


@app.route('/cheerbot')
def cheerbot():
    return render_template('cheerbot.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run("0.0.0.0",debug=True)
```

There could by a lot of reasons why that doesn't working, (like different directory of template files), but i think your code should working after this adjustment

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work. My HTML files are also all in the same folder, called templates.

Comment: Wait, did you run app through flask run command or you just open the file in browser ?

Comment: It looks like that. The jinja syntax shouldn't be there when you run python app, it should work like a sever on local machine  https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#what-to-do-if-the-server-does-not-start

Comment: Oh, I got it! I didn't run it through flask run command.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, the reason it was not working is because of my base.html referencing my style.js and style.css from a different directory. To Fix it I change the link tag to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='app.js')}}">
```

which before was hardcoded into my base.html file as

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/app.js">
```

What happened was, when I redirected to a new page, the page was stored in a different spot so my style sheet was not being imported.

Takeaway: use url_for() to not have to worry about this stuff.